# TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createRef is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I am new to React.js and just now i was learning the concept of `ref` in React. They have new *createRef API* in V16.3. I was trying to learn this from [REACT DOC's](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) like this -

```
import React from "react";

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
}

focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.textInput.current.focus();
}

render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                ref={this.textInput} />

            <input
                type="button"
                value="Focus the text input"
                onClick={this.focusTextInput}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

And I was Getting this Error -

**TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createRef is not a function**

Here is the screenshot -[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the right version of react installed, check your package.json

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not seem to have the correct version of react installed

Do this :

```
npm install --save react@16.4.0 react-dom@16.4.0
```

Comment: I am using the `^16.13.1` for both `react` and `react-dom` and this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't upgrade your react version, you can use legacy string refs (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

You set string for ref attribute:

```
<input
    type="text"
    ref="textInput" />
```

And access it like this:

```
this.refs.textInput.focus();
```

And don't forget to remove this part:

```
this.textInput = React.createRef();
this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
```